Running a Python function via the command line vs from another script
I am new to Python and attempting to get up to speed on the language.  In the past, I have written a good bit of PowerShell (PS) code.  These PS functions were written to be used in other functions or from the command line without any difference in how the function is called.  For example:
Send-Email -To "bobjones@gmail.com" -Cc "me@gmail.com" -Subject "My subject" -Body "This is what I have to say."

When running this from another script, I might send the results to an object by running something like results = Send-Email..., but other than that, there is no difference.
That command will work regardless of how I call it and has good help content and parameter auto-complete from my IDE.
However, with Python, it seems like I have to "design" each function to run either from the command line (e.g. using something like argparse / sys.argv) and call it like this:
send_email -to bobjones@gmail.com -cc me@gmail.com -subject "My subject" -body "This is what I have to say."

Or I write a "standard" def function as such:
def send_email(to: str, cc: str, subject: str, body: str):

And call it like this:
send_email("bobjones@gmail.com", "me@gmail.com", "My subject", "This is what I have to say.")

What I can't seem to do is write a function that can be executed from the command line AND another script, at least not in an elegant way (aka not using something like subprocess.  I hope I'm missing something.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

You're right, you can't. There's nothing in Python that automatically converts command-line arguments into function arguments. It's not intended to be used as a shell scripting language.

The difference is that PowerShell functions are integrated into the PowerShell command line. Other scripting languages are not integrated that way.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site works best on specific questions, but it seems like you're asking about a whole topic or looking for a discussion. Could you [edit] and turn this into a specific question? For example, it seems like you're confused about the term "function" in Python, so maybe you could ask about that. Check out [ask] for tips. Otherwise, there are other places that do discussions, like LearnPython on Reddit.

@Barmar, thank you.  I'll mark as the answer if you re-post as an answer.

Python isn't designed to integrate with shells like this. You can run a Python script from the shell, but it won't automatically run a function. You need to write wrapper code that parses the arguments from sys.argv and passes them to the function.
